# ReadStreamAsDT - Filehelpers and C# - How do I dynamically read in a CSV using filehelpers?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am attempting to read in a CSV dynamically via FileHelpers and work with the CSV data as a datatable.  My CSV files will not be the same.  They will have different column headers and different amounts of columns.  I am using the ReadStreamAsDT method, but it seems to still want a structured class to initialize the FileHelperEngine.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say, "My CSV files will not be the same", do you mean that each CSV file will have its own definition, or that each record in the CSV file could potentially be different?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I can't seem to find a way to instantiate the engine without giving it a concrete object.  I just want to pull ANY CSV file into a generic datatabase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use `FileHelpers.RunTime` and the `DelimitedClassBuilder` to create a `DataTable` from the file.  Here is my method.  If I get more time, I will explain this better.

```
private static DataTable CreateDataTableFromFile(byte[] importFile) {
    var cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("temp", ",") { IgnoreFirstLines = 0, IgnoreEmptyLines = true, Delimiter = "," };
    var ms = new MemoryStream(importFile); 
    var sr = new StreamReader(ms); 
    var headerArray = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    foreach (var header in headerArray) { 
        cb.AddField(header, typeof(string)); 
        cb.LastField.FieldQuoted = true; 
        cb.LastField.QuoteChar = '"'; 
    }
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());
    return engine.ReadStreamAsDT(sr);
}
```

Obviously, there is a lot of validation along with other logic taking place around this method, but I do not have much time right now to dive into it.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using the same approach but it throws "Out of memory exception" when file size is large.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx ?  You could leverage this library's parsing. It's fast and reliable.