# How to map 2d array in csv file to poco collection or dictionary of dictionary using FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, parsing, mapping, filehelpers

I have the following data structure in my csv file:

[image]

I want to either parse it into the following data structure :

```
[DelimitedRecord(","), IgnoreFirst(1)]
public class FxConversionRate
{
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "d/M/yyyy")]
    public DateTime Date;
    public string Currency;
    public double Rate;
}
```

Or else want to parse it into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>`

How can I accomplish either way? I do not want to modify the source csv table layout and believe I need to customize the import and mapping.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The following code snippet both, reads data from csv into a 2D array and also into a data structure (Dictionary of Dictionary in this case but could as well be the above proposed data structure `FxConversionRate`):

```
public class FxConversionTable
{
    public Dictionary<Currency, Dictionary<DateTime, double>> FxConversionRates{ get; set; } //key1 = Currency, key2 = DateTime, value = double
    public string[,] String2DArray{ get; set; }

    public FxConversionTable()
    {
        FxConversionRates = new Dictionary<Currency, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>();
    }

    public void ReadFxConversionRatesFromCsvFile(string pathFileName)
    {
        var strings = new List<List<string>>();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(pathFileName)))
        {
            //read symbol rows and parse
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    continue;

                var values = line.Split(',');

                //populate string array
                strings.Add(values.ToList());

                //header
                if (strings.Count == 1)
                {
                    foreach (var currencyString in values.Skip(1))
                    {
                        Currency ccy = (Currency) Enum.Parse(typeof (Currency), currencyString);
                        FxConversionRates.Add(ccy, new Dictionary<DateTime, double>());
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                //populate data collection
                var date = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                for (int i = 1; i < values.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var ccy = (Currency) Enum.Parse(typeof (Currency), strings[0][i]);
                    FxConversionRates[ccy].Add(date, Convert.ToDouble(values[i]));
                }
            }
        }

        String2DArray = FileIO.ListOfListTo2DArray<string>(strings);
    }
}
```

I am, however, still looking for a more generic solution via FileHelpers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.  It's not the most elegant solution but it works.  You will need to add plenty of error checking for things like missing columns or data or source file corruption etc.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("Data.csv");
        var tableData = CreateDataTableFromFile(fileData);

        DataColumn dateColumn = tableData.Columns["Date"];
        Dictionary<string, List<FxConversionRate>> rates = new Dictionary<string, List<FxConversionRate>>();
        foreach (DataColumn column in tableData.Columns)
        {
            if (column != dateColumn)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in tableData.Rows)
                {
                    FxConversionRate rate = new FxConversionRate();
                    rate.Currency = column.ColumnName;
                    rate.Date = DateTime.Parse(row[dateColumn].ToString());
                    rate.Rate = double.Parse(row[column].ToString());
                    if (!rates.ContainsKey(column.ColumnName))
                        rates.Add(column.ColumnName, new List<FxConversionRate>());
                    rates[column.ColumnName].Add(rate);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var key in rates.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found currency: {key}");
            foreach (var rate in rates[key])
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"   {rate.Date.ToShortDateString()} : {rate.Rate:###,###,##0.00}");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static DataTable CreateDataTableFromFile(byte[] importFile)
    {
        var cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("temp", ",") { IgnoreFirstLines = 0, IgnoreEmptyLines = true, Delimiter = "," };
        var ms = new MemoryStream(importFile);
        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        var headerArray = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        foreach (var header in headerArray)
        {
            cb.AddField(header, typeof(string));
            cb.LastField.FieldQuoted = true;
            cb.LastField.QuoteChar = '"';
        }
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());
        return engine.ReadStreamAsDT(sr);
    }
```

Note that the CreateDataTableFromFile routine was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045923/697159

Comment: I fail to see where you utilize the `FileHelpers` library, something I specifically asked for. I still upvoted for effort and I might actually get back to it if custom parsing and import via FileHelpers proves too cumbersome.

Comment: Then you missed the use of DelimitedClassBuilder :)

Comment: Oh and the ``var engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());``

Comment: my apologies, I missed that method. Nonetheless, I am a bit lost on the purpose of your methods. The idea of using FileHelpers was to map to a given data structure. Else I would just parse each row/columns manually. Yet, you use FileHelpers and still need to manually parse columns such as "Date"...what you presented seems to be a very specific, non-generic solution which begs the question why using FileHelpers in the first place. I can import the data and parse manually with less than 15 lines of code. I tried to avoid that using FileHelpers...

Comment: Also why are you taking the unnecessary route via Datatables? I will edit my question and present some snippet that does not peruse FileHelpers, I am still looking for a more generic version via FileHelpers.

Comment: FileHelpers will map your columns but you are basically wanting to pivot them, FileHelpers is reading in the data via CSV into the datatable.  This is allowing for dynamic columns and then my code pivots that into the layout that you want.  FileHelpers itself can NOT do the pivoting and rather than hard code currency columns which can be many, I build up the class using FileHelpers DelimitedClassBuilder which very nicely gets the data into a usable DataTable.

Comment: The main difference between my way and your way, is that you are relying on hard coded currency names where mine is all dynamic.  If you add a new currency for some reason (say for example there was a new virtual currency), mine would handle this automatically.  You would have to rebuild your code to insert the new currency into the enum type you've defined.  Personally I feel there is little need to switch to FileHelpers from your own code if your own is working for you because you can't really get much more generic with FileHelpers

Answer (score 2):

You can use some fancy LINQ.

Helpful note: with FileHelpers it's easier to separate the class which defines the file format (`FxConversionRateSpec`) from the destination class (`FxConversionRate`) and map between the two.

```
// destination object
public class FxConversionRate
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
}

// file format specification (FileHelpers class)
[DelimitedRecord(","), IgnoreFirst(1)]
public class FxConversionRateSpec
{
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "d/M/yyyy")]
    public DateTime Date;
    public double[] Rates;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // trimmed down contents...
        var contents =
        @"DATE,AUD,CAD,CHF" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"1/1/2000,88,71,3" + Environment.NewLine +
        @"2/1/2000,82,83,86";

        // get the records
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<FxConversionRateSpec>();
        var records = engine.ReadString(contents);

        // get the header
        var currencies = contents
            .Substring(0, contents.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)) // take the first line
            .Split(',') // split into currencies
            .Skip(1); // skip the 'Date' column

        // as IEnumerable<FxConversionRate>
        var rates = records.SelectMany( // for each record of Date, Double[]
            record => currencies.Zip(record.Rates, (c, r) => new { Currency = c, Rate = r}) // combine the rates array with the currency labels
                .Select( // for each of the anonymous typed records Currency, Double
                    currencyRate => 
                            new FxConversionRate
                                {
                                    Date = record.Date,
                                    Currency = currencyRate.Currency,
                                    Rate = currencyRate.Rate
                            }));

        Assert.AreEqual(6, rates.Count(), "Exactly 6 records were expected");

        Assert.That(rates.Single(x => x.Date == new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) && x.Currency == "AUD" && x.Rate == 88d) != null);
        Assert.That(rates.Single(x => x.Date == new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) && x.Currency == "CAD" && x.Rate == 71d) != null);
        Assert.That(rates.Single(x => x.Date == new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) && x.Currency == "CHF" && x.Rate == 3d) != null);

        Assert.That(rates.Single(x => x.Date == new DateTime(2000, 1, 2) && x.Currency == "AUD" && x.Rate == 82d) != null);
        Assert.That(rates.Single(x => x.Date == new DateTime(2000, 1, 2) && x.Currency == "CAD" && x.Rate == 83d) != null);
        Assert.That(rates.Single(x => x.Date == new DateTime(2000, 1, 2) && x.Currency == "CHF" && x.Rate == 86d) != null);

        Console.WriteLine("All tests passed OK.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Note it would be quite feasible to create a `Dictionary` instead, especially with the `ToDictionary()` LINQ extension.