# OleDb parameter to be used in from clause

Tags: c#, .net, csv, oledb

I have the following code to read a CSV file and populate a DataTable:

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                  ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    return dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
```

This snipped works great, but code analysis complains about it ([CA2100](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182310.aspx)). The way I build the query string should be changed so I can use parameters.

I am trying to fix this, but it seems the usual OleDbParameter usage does not work. The query is built with the parameter name instead of its value:

```
            string sql = @"SELECT * FROM @param";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                  ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@param", fileName));
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    return dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Code Analysis doesn't know everything. This query can only be built dynamically, as the `FROM` part of a query can't be parameterized. Suppress the warning -- you did "review the query for security vulnerabilities". (You may want to double check how to escape file names, though -- `[` and `]` are legal characters, so at the very least `]` will need to be escaped. I'm not sure on the rules for the Jet driver.)

Comment: normally table names are not allowed as parameters

Comment: you can use [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/N_FileHelpers_Dynamic.htm)
and you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585726/readstreamasdt-filehelpers-and-c-sharp-how-do-i-dynamically-read-in-a-csv-us) link.

Comment: I think to use parameters you will need to pass them into a stored procedure.